# How to append indices

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, counter

I have the following code:

```html
indices_to_remove= []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if (df.speed.values[i] <= 15 ):
            counter += 1
            if counter > 600:
               indices_to_remove.append(i)        

        else:
            counter= 0

df= df.drop (indices_to_remove, axis=0)
```

The main goal of this code is to loop through all the rows in my dataset, and in case there are more than 600 consecutive rows that has a speed value less than 15. The code will add the rows indices to the indices_to_remove and then all of these rows will be dropped.

Comment: Could you share how your dataframe looks like!

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question. I hope you can help. So basically I wish to delete rows from zero to 1000.

Comment: So if the row has `value<15` you want to delete it? Can you clarify your `counter>600` condition~

Comment: yes Exactly. There are two conditions that need to be met before deleting. First, the value< 15, and secondly, the number of consecutive rows that has a value less than 15 should be at least 600 consecutive rows. @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Also, have in mind that I have more than one set of more than 600 consecutive rows that has a value less than 15. @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Alright, I have tried to simplify your code for you! Check my answer below and see if it makes sense @alex-davies !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do two things in parallel, getting indexes to remove and also counting 600 consecutive values which are less than 15. I would separate these two ideas into two steps.

1. Find all indexes for which values are less than 15
2. After that, count indexes which are consecutive
3. If we have more than 600 of those indexes, perform the deletion

```
indices_to_remove= []

#Get all indexes to remove from the dataframe
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if (df.speed.values[i] <= 15 ):
        indices_to_remove.append(i)

#Have a counter which keeps track of 600 consecutive indexes less than 15
counter = 0
max_counter = -1
for idx in range(len(indices_to_remove)-1):

    #If the indexes were consecutive, keep a counter
    if ((indices_to_remove[idx+1] - indices_to_remove[idx]) == 1):
        counter += 1

    #Else if non consecutive indexes are found, track the last maximum counter and reset the original counter
    else:
        if counter > max_counter:
            max_counter = counter
        counter = 0

if max_counter > 600:
    df = df.drop(indices_to_remove, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but building on what you've got there:

```
indices_to_remove= []
indices_counter = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):

        if (df.speed.values[i] <= 15 ):
            counter += 1

            indices_counter.append(i)

            if counter > 600:
                commit = True

        elif commit:
            indices_to_remove.extend(indices_counter)
            indices_counter = []
            commit = False
            counter= 0

        else:
            indices_counter = []
            commit = False
            counter= 0

df= df.drop(indices_to_remove, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary of the indices where the consecutive speed is less than or equals to 15.

```
indices_dict = {}
k = 0
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if (df.speed.values[i] <= 15 ):
        try:
            indices_dict[k].append(i)
        except KeyError:
            indices_dict[k] = [i]
    else:
        k += 1

lol_to_remove = [ v for k,v in indices_dict.items() if len(v)>= 600 ] # This is a list of lists (lol)
indices_to_remove = [i for v in lol_to_remove for i in v ] # flatten the list

df = df.drop(indices_to_remove, axis=0)
```